# How to call second cell from first cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Good afternoon, i have tableview controller and in table i have 2 cell (DefaultCell and ExpansionCell). Question: how to call ExpansionCell from Defaultcell when they press.

Comment: Show code you've tried as a [mcve] please. Read [ask] on the way.

Comment: You don't need two different cells.  Just have a single cell and alter it's state depending on if it is expanded or not.  Start out simple without any animations and then once that works you can add animations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use **notificationCenter** to post a notification in any cell and listen to it in another

Or

Implement **didSelectRowAt** and get kind of pressed cell and loop for all other cells of the table

**Note:** I don't really know your implementation but if it's a type of a default and a expansion cells , it may be combined in one cell with a simple play in constraints with dynamic tableView height technique

Comment: Hello! and thx for answer! i have standard filling function for Defaultcell to display them. and I want that when you click under it appeared ExpansionCell.

Comment: you want to insert ExpansionCell below default when clicked ???

Comment: yes, like this [https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell?utm_source=mybridge&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=read_more](folding-cell).unfortunately their library does not work, so I'm trying to do something my own

Comment: it's the same cell with 2 views inside it default view and expansion view hidden that takes a more height and expanded with animation

Comment: ye, i know that, i read, I can call the second call from the first but I do not understand how to cause

Comment: you need not 2 cells it's only 1 cell and you should manage collapse(default view) and expansion(when cell clicked in default mode) according to current state of cell

Comment: hmm, i read [ http://codebasecamp.com/2016/12/02/Expandable-TableView/](this) but for a dynamic table, so that it always opens with a fixed number of calls. It did not work, apparently because I do not have much experience

Comment: see , if want to do what in you mind which is 2 cells and call them , then when a cell is clicked in cellForRowAt check it's type if it's default replace the model type in that index with expanded and call reloadDate function of tableview

Comment: oke, i will read about it :) Ty ^-^

Answer (score -1):

just a hint how you make it:

**A-** you have 2 views in one cell

```
1- main cell 

2- expanded cell
```

**B**- you make first(main view) above the second(expanded view)

**C-** implement this for dynamic height for the table view

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
```

**D-** in **didSelectRow** make an animation to show the expanded view below/above/on as you like the first view

I can make the code but it's kinda long

Comment: Hello! and thx for answer :) i have a main cell (which is filled with standard information) and I want that when you click on it appeared a expanded cell from below... but people say this can be done through one cell.
I found one lesson but did not have time to look at it yet. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=itbok1NZvss)